Why I can't query the string to date using whereRaw method throught query builder?
I have this string date which is for example "January 3, 2024'. Now I want it to compare if it greater than today's date for filtering purposes.
$query->whereRaw('STR_TO_DATE(validity, "%M %d, %Y") >= ?', [Carbon::now()]);

I've been trying these but same error
$query->where(DB::raw
$query->whereRaw
$query->whereDate

array_merge_recursive(): Argument #2 must be of type array, string given


Can you provide the full error message? Passing Carbon::now() should work, but you can also try Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()

Hi. Thanks. That was the full message of the error and if I use this one
$query->whereDate('validity', '>=', Carbon::now())
It has no error, but most of my validity are strings so I need it to convert first. I'm dying lol

You can use DB::raw for just the column, $query->whereDate(DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(validity, "%M %d, %Y")'), '>=', Carbon::now()) and see if that helps

Thanks but it says Illegal offset type.

Very odd, it shouldn't do that. Can you show your full query? There may be a hint there.

here is part of my code

$soa_list = $soa_list->where(function ($query) use ($for_filter) {
              if (isset($this->tab) && $this->tab !== 'all') {
                  $tab = strtoupper($this->tab);
                  $tab = str_replace('-', ' ', $tab);         
                  $query->where(function ($query) {
                      $query->whereDate(DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(validity, "%M %d, %Y")'), '>=', Carbon::now());
                  });
          
              }
          });



Please [edit] your question and add the code there. Most code is unreadable in comments.

Try where instead of whereDate, it doesn't seem to have the same sort of check for the column
